# How to send sales transaction emails?

Tags: magento2.3, transactional-mail

I like to send emails for my sales order.

1. If the order is placed status as "Processing". (email send automatically) it's okay
2. Processing to "Dispatch" (**not having the option to set dispatch**)
3. Dispatch to "Shipments" (this too I assigned email with tracking details)
4. Shipments to "Delivered" (**not having option to set delivered**)
5. For all this order I need to send emails to customers.

Comment: there is a checkbox option about `Submit` button related to `Notification to customer`.

Comment: Yeah i know that, but it directlly goes from "Processing" to "shipments"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to use event `sales_order_state_change_before` and check `previous state/status` and `current state/status.` According to this pass data in template variable and use in email template.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Namespace\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

class Statechange implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $escaper;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(        
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        Escaper $escaper,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {

        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->logger = $logger;

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
        $previousState = $order->getState();
        $currentState = $transport->getState();
        if ($order instanceof \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel) {
           if($previousState == 'processing ' && $currentState == 'complete') {
                // processing to complete logic here
                $this->sendEmail($order,$previousState,$currentState);
           }else if($previousState == 'new' && $currentState == 'cancel') {
                // new to cance logic here
                $this->sendEmail($order,$previousState,$currentState);
           }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function sendEmail($order,$previousState,$currentState)
    {
            try {
                $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
                $sender = [
                    'name' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('Test'),
                    'email' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('abc@gmail.com'),
                ];
                $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('email_demo_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->setTemplateVars([
                        'order'  => $order,
                        'previousState'  => $previousState,
                        'currentState'  => $currentState,
                    ])
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo($order->getCustomerEmail())
                    ->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
                $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->debug($e->getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```